# How to display data from database in to a webpage with a scroll bar below

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a page like this before, but I put the data from the database on a table because it don't have so many columns. But this time, I'm going to need a scroll bar bellow because there are so many columns I need to display. I don't know if I'm going to use CSS here or JavaScript. Please help thanks btw.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are expected to attempt on your own, before asking. You can start by searching here and elsewhere for "css horizontal scroll".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`table
{width:100%;
white-space : nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;}` 
  
 You can set `height` and `width` of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width=300px;overflow:scroll">
 <table></table>
</div>
```